# Who can help me please with a start with Low Search

Tags: low-search

It must be me, but after many many hours struggeling and reading the manual I am not getting any result.
We have a rather complicated website and my client wants to be able to search and refine search.

I have absolutely no idea how I can make Low Search work, I must be doing something fundamental wrong. The only thing that works is search in categories.

I must search in this channel X with many fields and checkboxes.
And refine search after a search order as well.
Where and how do I put the code in a search form? I just get a repetion of code (just as many as there are entrees for this channel)
This does not work

```
{exp:low_search:form result_page="zoek/resultaat"}
{exp:channel:entries
          channel="X"
          dynamic="no"
          orderby="title"
          sort="asc"
          disable="categories|member_data|pagination"
        }
<fieldset>
                <legend>{piano-en-toetsen}piano en toetsen</legend>
                <ul class="forms-inline-list">
                     {options:piano-en-toetsen}
                <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="piano-en-toetsen" name="piano-en-toetsen[]" value="{option_value}"{checked}>
            <label for="checkbox">{option_value}</label>
                </li>


                    {/options:piano-en-toetsen}
                    </ul> 
                </fieldset><br>

    {/exp:channel:entries}
                                          <button type="submit">Search</button>
{/exp:low_search:form}
```

---

And this does not work either

```
    <label for="option">Option</label>
    <select name="search:piano-en-toetsen" id="option">
      <option value="">-- Select option --</option>
      {exp:low_options:piano-en-toetsen parse="inward"}
        {if option:group != ''}<optgroup label="{option:group}">{/if}
        {options}
          <option value="{option:value}"{if option:value == low_search_search:piano-en-toetsen} selected{/if}>
            {option:label}
          </option>
        {/options}
        {if option:group != ''}</optgroup>{/if}
      {/exp:low_options:piano-en-toetsen}
    </select>
```

This is nothing as well:

```
{field:piano-en-toetsen}
```

---

And this, exactly as it says in the manual of EE, does not work either

```
<select name="piano-en-toetsen">
                {options:piano-en-toetsen}
                        <option value="{option_value}"{selected}>{option_name}</option>
                {/options:piano-en-toetsen}
        </select>
```

Comment: Your exact question isn't really clear. Try and explain what you're trying to accomplish, what you're expecting to get with given code, and what you're actually getting. Also, as a side note, there's always the option to get [implementation aid](http://gotolow.com/contact).

Comment: We try to make a search form for LowSearch. The form should perform a search and refine the search in channels with fiells with checkboxes and radio buttons where the content is defined by other fields. The basic setup of such a search form is not clear to us, and we cannot find the answer in the documentation, nor in answers here on Stackexchange nor in answers on the discussionforum from the addon itself. We just get a repetition of raw code, not the actual checkboxes that the user can use to perform a search. About the second part of your answer, we have send you an email.